# Saving strings to a text file in p5

Tags: javascript, p5.js

How do you save strings to a text file that is **already embedded in the program?** I'm not trying to create a new text file with my data, I have a text file in my program already and I want to save my data there.

```
var name;

function preload()
{
  dataFile = loadStrings('App Data.txt');
}

var data = []

function setup()
{
  createCanvas(650, 500);
  bgcolor = [96, 253, 201];
  background(bgcolor);
  enterName = createInput();
  nameButton = createButton('Enter');
}

function draw()
{
  textSize(80);
  fill(255);
  textAlign(CENTER)
  text("What's Your\nName?", width/2, 200);
  enterName.position(213, 350);
  enterName.size(170, 30);
  enterName.style('font-size', '21px');
  nameButton.position(enterName.x + enterName.width, 350);
  nameButton.size(70, 36);
  nameButton.style('font-size', '21px');
  nameButton.mousePressed(nameButtonFunct);
}

function nameButtonFunct()
{
    var name = enterName.value();
    append(data, name);
    append(dataFile, data[0]);
    saveStrings(data[0], dataFile);
    print(data[0]);
}
```

You're going to need to import a blank .txt file to make this run properly.

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far

Comment: Are you asking about Processing or p5.js? Can you please post a [mcve]?

Comment: Are you trying to persist the data in the file? If so, you probably want to use [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) rather than a file. The browser doesn't have access to the file system by default, so you'd have to add a server which is a bit more involved than the dev server you're probably using to host `App Data.txt`. `saveStrings()` triggers a download that may not be saved over the original file.